# How can I use ActiveRecord inside my custom gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm building my custom gem and I want to expose an activerecord model. How can I do this?

What I have now is:

```
require 'active_record'
module MyGem
  class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  end
end
```

and in my gemspec file:

```
spec.add_dependency 'activerecord', '>= 5.0.0'
```

and when I try do up my application that have this gem, I got:

```
`<module:MyGem>': uninitialized constant MyGem::ApplicationRecord
```

Comment: Well yes, where's your `ApplicationRecord` class? Moreover, did you think about how you are going to provide connection information for it? And maybe you also need migrations in that gem? There's a lot of moving parts in "using activerecord from a gem".

Comment: ApplicationRecord is on active_record gem. I already have a migration that is copied to app directory. Connection information will come from app connection settings. Am I right?

Comment: "ApplicationRecord is on active_record gem" - is it, though? If it was, then it'd be found. Hint: look for it in your rails app.

Comment: It should be, because I'm requiring 'active_record' on top of my class.

Comment: No, that class is not a part of active_record gem. You normally see it in rails apps, where it is a direct descendant of `ActiveRecord::Base` class.

Comment: @zarazan: nope, it isn't. Did you read the post? It isn't a part of any gem. It's generated as part of a new rails app, when you run `rails new`.

Comment: That works @SergioTulentsev. Thanks :)

Comment: And how can I test my gem with RSpec using a Rails app?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ApplicationRecord isn't in the ActiveRecord gem as I originally thought. I would just use the base active record class as your super class.

```
require 'active_record'
module MyGem
  class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```